# How to set database information in phpMyFAQ?

Tags: php

Error: Please install your version of phpMyFAQ once again or send us a bug report.

DB error: No database selected

Query:

CREATE TABLE faqadminlog (
id int(11) NOT NULL,
time int(11) NOT NULL,
usr int(11) NOT NULL,
text text NOT NULL,
ip text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id));

Comment: Where did you run your query ? Select your DB schema first !

Comment: but how to select DB schema ?
no idea please help

Comment: That's why I ask the 1st question. Where do you execute the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select database schema, first create the schema if not exist:

```
CREATE DATABASE testing DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = 'utf8'
```

To select database schema:

```
USE testing
```

Comment: which one select database, like information_schema ya performance_schema ?

Comment: Don't understand. These two are system schema. Don't touch.

Comment: please solve this problem step wise.

Comment: The answer already explained the details. 2 steps only.